# Mapping click points on different resolutions

Tags: click, coordinates, heatmap

I am preparing a heatmap app. The problem I came up with are different screen resolutions. Do you know how to compute/transform click coords to my resolution?

Let's say my desired resolution is 1024x768. I want all clicks from different resolutions to map my resolution so clicked objects coords would be the same for all tested resolutions. Thanks in advance!